# Как заблокировать пользователя discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Как сделать, чтобы бот заблокировал пользователя ?Не в каком либо канале, а  самом дискорде, чтобы пользователь не мог писать боту в ЛС

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не может быть реализовано так как бот не умеет блокировать людей в лс. В discord.py api вообщем то даже такого метода нет.